# What files will be changed vs added when I do an hg pull and hg update

Tags: version-control, mercurial, dvcs, pull

So in Subversion when I do an `svn up` I get a list of files that were added, modified, deleted, and conflicted.

When I do an `hg pull` then `hg up -v` it just displays a list of: `getting file.ext` but I have no way of know if that file is new or already existed. Is there a way to have Mercurial display the same sort of meta about if the file was added, modified, or deleted?

Does Mercurial offer any ability to do what I am asking?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the status command to list changes in file status between the working copy and its parent revision or **between any two revisions**. It gives you output like this:

```
$ hg status --rev .:tip
M hgext/keyword.py
M mercurial/cmdutil.py
M mercurial/commands.py
M mercurial/context.py
M mercurial/patch.py
A tests/test-encoding-align
A tests/test-encoding-align.out
```

which corresponds to this update:

```
$ hg update -v
resolving manifests
getting hgext/keyword.py
getting mercurial/cmdutil.py
getting mercurial/commands.py
getting mercurial/context.py
getting mercurial/patch.py
getting tests/test-encoding-align
getting tests/test-encoding-align.out
7 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
```

**Edit:** You can create a `preupdate` hook to always get this information as part of your updates. I happen to be on Windows right now, and here this hook works:

```
[hooks]
preupdate = hg status --rev .:%HG_PARENT1%
```

Replace `%HG_PARENT1%` with `$HG_PARENT1` on Unix-like systems. This should make the Mercurial experience even more Subversion-like :-)

Comment: Thanks! I can do an "hg id" get the revision I am currently at then to an "hg pull" then "hg stat --rev PREVIOUS_REV:tip" and it does exactly what I wanted

Comment: James: thanks for accepting this answer, I'm glad I could help! :-)

Comment: Is there a way to get the 7 files that has been updated ? Which ones have ?

Answer (score 18):

Omni has your answer, and I voted for it, but just to show all the options:

Before pulling

- hg incoming # shows the changesets you'll get
- hg incoming --verbose # shows the changesets you'll get including a file list for each
- hg incoming --patch # shows the full diffs of all the changesets you'll be getting

After pulling (but not updating):

- hg log -r .:tip  # shows the changesets you got
- hg log --verbose -r .:tip # shows the changesets you got including a file list for each
- hg log --patch -r .:trip # shows the full diffs of all the changesets you got

Answer (score 6):

The `hg incoming --stat` command does something like what you're asking.  Also, if you're updating to a new revision, you can do `hg diff --git -r <rev>` and it will give you a diff that shows which files are new.

Comment: hg incoming --stat still doesn't tell me if a file is new or not and I would have to run hg diff on each file to see. The worst case I can recurse the directory before I update and see what is new after I update but that seems so terrible. It just surprises me that this information is more easily available

Comment: @James - I wonder if a specialized template for 'log' wouldn't handle this.  I will investigate a bit and see.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `hg incoming` with bundles, to apply Martin's answer to changes you haven't actually pulled yet.

```
> cd myrepo
# Get the latest revision in my copy
> hg tip
changeset:   17:5005ce2dc418
.
.
.
# Get a bundle file of changes, but don't put them in myrepo yet
> hg incoming --bundle changes.bundle
# Overlay the bundle on myrepo and do hg status as if I've already pulled
> hg -R changes.bundle status --rev 17:tip
A addedfile
M modifiedfile
.
.
.
# Changes are good! Pull from bundle
hg pull changes.bundle
```