# Asking mercurial to show a list of the files to update when updating

Tags: mercurial

I didn't see anything [on the documentation](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#update) that allows me to see which files are updated **when updating** my working directory. Is there any way to ask mercurial to show this?

I presume I could always run `hg diff` before `hg update`, but that would be redundant and slow down the process if I want to do this every time I update (I presume that  `hg update` collects a list of files to update itself, is that right?).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What files will be changed vs added when I do an hg pull and hg update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277334/what-files-will-be-changed-vs-added-when-i-do-an-hg-pull-and-hg-update)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `hg update -v` will do what you want:

```
$ hg init hgtest
$ cd hgtest
$ echo this > afile
$ hg commit -A -m first
adding afile
$ hg update -v null
resolving manifests
removing afile
0 files updated, 0 files merged, 1 files removed, 0 files unresolved
$ hg update -v
resolving manifests
getting afile
1 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
```